# 550 5.7.501 Service unavailable, Client host blocked using Spamhaus

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have a mail relay server with postfix configured in the company that I work and we are doing a new Virtual Machine with a new mail relay server because we are changing to another network.

The configurations are the same as the other machine but it gives me the error that I put in the title of the question.

We already entered on the website of the spamhaus and unblocked but it is still the same.

As anyone got any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Delisting from Spamhaus is not istantaneous.

Also, because Spamhaus blacklists are DNS based, they "suffer" from the normal caching of DNS servers.

On top of that, mail servers may have additional local caching to reduce system/network load, so you might have to wait a couple of hours or more before the destination server updates its records and lets your mail through.